# How to install a pae version of linux 3.0?

Tags: 11.04, kernel, compiling, pae

Was wondering how I would go about installing Linux Kernel 3.0 with pae enabled in Natty?  Is there a PPA available with this included or do I have to compile from scratch?

Comment: compile it... :)

Comment: I've been trying to find a good tutorial for this.  Any recommendations?

Comment: Interesting xD http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OTUwMg
`So what are the big changes?

NOTHING. Absolutely nothing. Sure, we have the usual two thirds driver changes, and a lot of random fixes, but the point is that 3.0 is *just* about renumbering, we are very much *not* doing a KDE-4 or a Gnome-3 here. No breakage, no special scary new features, nothing at all like that. We've been doing time-based releases for many years now, this is in no way about features. If you want an excuse for the renumbering, you really should look at the time-based one ("20 years") instead.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to try directly installing the Oneiric kernel version, you can pull the .deb files you need from:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux

Otherwise, you can try automated daily builds of the current upstream kernels here:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/current/
Though the -pae i386 kernel is not available here yet.

Answer (score 2):

Go here and download it. Look at the bottom [Download linux-image-3.0-1-generic-pae](http://packages.ubuntu.com/km/oneiric/linux-image-3.0-1-generic-pae)